# Return from hibernation with black screen

Tags: macbook, hibernate

In a macbook pro, with OSX Snow Leopard, I use hibernation thanks to the widget "deep sleep". But when it wakes up, the screen is fully white, lots of lights. I wonder if it can be somehow modified to be completely black, so while I am at a conference, people do not notice it

Comment: Have you considered setting the brightness to 0 before you put it to sleep?

Comment: no, but I will have a look at that!